# How does an end user get their certificates in Hyperledger Fabric?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I am new to hyperledger and have been reading the documentation and playing around with the sample codes. I am a bit confused on how the registration/enrollement/authentication of new users is done in hyperledger. I hope someone could clarify these points for me:

1. After a user is registered by an Admin. How does the user receive the password (i.e. secret) and the private signing certificates? (Assuming the user does not belong to the network and only interact with hyperledger through an SDK application).
2. If the user is already enrolled by an Admin (i.e. the secret and username have been stored in the network) how can he/she change their password?

I appreciate the help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The registration

- When you register a user, you must define his name. Then, you get a password (or you can define it when you register the user). How do you receive or send those credentials, is your own issue, i.e. the user can define his name and then you pass him the password, or he can define both credentials and pass them to the admin of the Server CA.
- In spite of it, Fabric CA gives you some options to improve the security. You can define how many times the same password can be used for enrollment. You define it when you start your server, more info about it [here](http://hyperledger-fabric-ca.readthedocs.io/en/latest/users-guide.html#starting-the-server). You limit the number of times that the same secret (or password) can be used for enrollment. If you set the value to 1, the Fabric CA server allows passwords to only be used once for a particular enrollment ID

The enrollment

- The user will use the credentials to enroll. The certificates will be sent to the user that is enrolling, so you will ensure that only the user will get those certificates.

Then, the user will use the certificates generated by the Server CA to interact with the Blockchain. The user won't need his credentials anymore.